# Probability of ballot ending in a tie

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I am fairly sure this is a studied problem, but I am no expert. We have a ballot with $k$ candidates and $n \geq k$ paritcipants, each participant voting once, each candidate having equal strength, so that the individual votes are uniformly distributed.

I would like to calculate the probability of the ballot ending in a tie, and possibly to study how for fixed $k$ this changes with $n$ (and asympotically with $n$ and $k$, perhaps).

That's how I would approach the problem. The number of possible outcomes is the total number of weak $k$-compositions of $n$, that is ${n+k-1}\choose{k-1}  $. Letting
$x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k ) \in \mathbb N^k$
the set of the favourable outcomes $F$ is given by

$$F=\left\{x \in \mathbb N^k \,\Big| \, \sum_{j=1}^kx_j=n, \, \|x\|_{\infty}=x_i, \, i \in K, K \subseteq \{1, \ldots ,k\}, \, \mbox{card(K)} \geq 2   \right \}$$

How do I find the cardinality of $F$?

Let next suppose that each voter has now fixed $l \leq k$ distinct choices instead of a single vote (if repeated choices are allowed we fall back in the problem above). How does the problem change?

Comment: Perhaps calculating the complement would be easier: determine number of outcomes where there is a unique winner, then subtracting from the total to get number of ties

Comment: In addition to the comment of Tony Mathew, I question whether your cardinality approach will work, because not all possible outcomes (or all possible satisfying outcomes) are equally likely.  You have to be very careful when attempting to apply [Stars and Bars theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) to a probability problem.

Comment: @user2661923 Well I am assuming uniform distribution for the individual vote, that's what I meant by equal strength of the candidates, so I am effectively forcing this into a combinatorics problem. I may need to edit the question. Or perhaps I misunderstood your point.

Comment: Are the voters independent? That is, are the voters like flips of different coins, where the outcome of one voter gives no information about the outcome of the others?

Comment: @Mike Earnest, yes they are. All election outcomes have same probability, and all voters are n uniform i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v.s taking values on the canonical basis of R^k

Comment: Those two statements in your last comment are contradictory. If all voters are independently uniform, then not all outcomes are equally likely. Consider $2$ candidates (A and B) and two voters. The probability A gets two votes is $(1/2)\times (1/2)=1/4$, because each voter has  $1/2$ chance to vote A. Similarly, B gets two votes with probability $1/4$. The leftover chance that A and B each get one vote is $1-1/4-1/4=1/2$. As you can see, not all outcomes are equally likely.

Comment: @MikeEarnest you are right in that but I doubt your approach works in general, see my counterexample below

Answer (score 2):

#### Your mistake

First of all, your formulation of the problem is incorrect. To see this, it suffices to look at a small case, with just $k=2$ candidates and $n=2$ participants.

According to you, the number of total outcomes is $\binom{2+2-1}{2-1}=3$. These three outcomes are the three possible vote distributions: either $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$, or $(0,2)$. Only the distribution of $(1,1)$ results in a tie. There is one favorable outcome out of three total outcomes, so the probability should be $1/3$, right?

Wrong. Since both voters are equally likely to vote for each candidate, and the votes are independent, the probability of the outcome $(2,0)$ where both voters vote for the first candidate is $(1/2)\times (1/2)=1/4$. Similarly, the probability of $(0,2)$ is $1/4$. Therefore, the probability of a tie is $1-1/4-1/4=1/2$.

The problem with your method, based on counting the number of favorable vote distribution, is that *not every vote distribution is equally likely*, as the last calculation shows.

#### Approximate result

Let $X_1,\dots,X_k$ be random variables representing the number of votes each candidate receives. The distribution of the random vector $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is quite complicated, so I strongly doubt that you will get an exact answer to your question. However, we can approximate this distribution using a technique called Poissonization.

Let $Z_1,\dots,Z_k$ be independent Poisson random variables, each with expected value $n/k$. The random vector $(Z_1,\dots,Z_k)$ is a good approximation for the vector $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$, in the following sense.

> **Theorem:** The distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is exactly equal to the conditional distribution of $(Z_1,\dots,Z_k)$, conditional on $Z_1+\dots+Z_k=n$.

Since the expected value of $Z_1+\dots+Z_k$ is $n$, and since $Z_1+\dots+Z_k$ is tightly concentrated around its mean, the effect of conditioning is not too severe, so we conclude that $(Z_1,\dots,Z_k)$ is a good approximation for $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$. This theorem is helpful because while the variables $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are dependent, the variables $Z_1,\dots,Z_k$ are independent, so they are easier to handle.

For the Poissonized version of the event, the probability that there is a tie for largest among the Poisson variables $(Z_1,\dots,Z_k)$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(\text{tie})
&=1-P(\text{unique winner})
\\&=1-k\sum_{m=0}^\infty P(Z_1=m)\cdot P(Z_1<m)^{k-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

This is because the probability a particular candidate wins with $m$ points is $P(Z_1=m)\cdot P(Z_1<m)^{k-1}$, because the other $k-1$ candidates need fewer than $m$ points. We then sum over all possible $m$, then multiply by $k$ because any candidate can win. To be clear, $P(Z_1=m)=e^{-n/k}(n/k)^m/m!$, while $P(Z_1<m)=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}e^{-n/k}(n/k)^r/r!$, so the above formula can be computed easily.

Here are my findings for how well this approximation works, for some sample values of $k$ and $n$.

| k | n | Actual probability (simulated, 90 000 trials) | Poisson approximation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10 | 0.2461 | 0.20723 |
| 3 | 50 | 0.11394 | 0.09847 |
| 3 | 200 | 0.05603 | 0.05049 |
| 10 | 50 | 0.24001 | 0.25639 |
| 10 | 200 | 0.13599 | 0.14724 |
| 10 | 500 | 0.08951 | 0.09839 |
| 40 | 50 | 0.44397 | 0.45721 |
| 40 | 100 | 0.3796 | 0.3843 |
| 40 | 1000 | 0.17173 | 0.17388 |

Here is the code to produce this table: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVXLbts4FF3bX3EBLyo5qmP3sQkmBYoCBQaYRfZBINASFXEkkSpJ1Qk6@fbMuaQkPxLANine17nnXMr9s6@N/vz6WlnTUSd8TarrjfVUicIbq0SbUSEVfuVTvwxeVugSy@gXn7Kw4vsoM3L1UFUtNkVtVCGjTWm/XJayQhGlk/RmuVyUwou8N7A4uiW6Tz5ntNumGfHm67T5tOXdcrFYJLvtdM67aBgPZ58vsw/vdtt5yz4PqKqHLvfcGBeFfbvFYWUsNRlpUppOYN0gpeh7a57giyPnjM7jQaIzalLYnepgvMux4oyTzAXY3FskSqoPf5oX@o/@6BfixZpBlwlCgCt9OZ7E3PHwQxoJA/HSqk4iTajJ1P02XuYFQgJ199sHWlMT28i5h6BEolNuICqUFywCepMImMVKQExDH2nHUE@S3l8GPdAV2FouuNdOPCUnvgi10g9W08nhJixJl9K3W/oUG5k4onOSbkZR3FAU0jnJHW3f9nIasLgIALYzlpojpnPH65PCEdR7qjKiVnR7ANHXDR5W5I0XLR1U29Jekvw14MkbWNjohi5hYnabjdKV0so/p1QlnKIUGYGENf08Pga@ab1OJuZXxN9DLa08D1OOfC2p7ypiOgTdRbSjTzrdxd8CHe1x5TgPjk6rzVmKstoQmomtBI5X9DfAgoz2mXHhDLfXkJOeIxwqW7MXe9XCCeyJojAWN/mxfUamxR2M@Ygol79yTgAZko9cO72wtzLYp8vWHZXdZcRXJBB@hVsNssJ@vabt5msa5MZnRf8Y0x9bJdydfwfnEVxYycLLktEH16EPk34O3xsCfisLjyztIB038Q5KTNOb1i4dQ7vr24j0mrplKPu9LAPVWh7IS9txSX4OlHObkJBtUxM8yPKQT4rE9YreqURvYYKfeYJQ@0cti4ZUNQEYs47iO9GBskOtippMUQzWhSDMnI4IgRYCYwBdh3GQFqdCU9Ua4UGjLJRTRgfCUOIE9ISap66jb4EQVizMVpw7gUEyCAL99fgP4aGkKHmUYuX48l7hbhVicCNhjF2bwyRaKL7YWynwplvI1smpTjVOK/zFXGMcgZn@TXT@3mLAL22Rh47@ioJmJFzkYeRFcSfKxQxWPuI9g7Z0ZBKgMdGSDpIe@eJEyTsJ4kxUA@@HDQX0k9IzgWG2x1fVDmI2kDoalvGP8vX1fw)

Comment: Perhaps for large n. You observe the distribution is joint dependent binomial and approximate with an independent joint poisson. In the case k=n  we can compute your answer in  closed form, it equals 1- k/e sum_m^Infty LowerGammaInc[m,1]/(m-1)!m!, which if i didn't make a mistake when k=2 is    about 0.3. Far off 0.5 of n=k=2. The effect of condition seems to be indeed felt  and the approximation doesn't seem to hold (in general).

Comment: Also,  is when n is small that the problem is interesting

Comment: I did the best I could do.

Comment: Well yes, thanks for that, and for correcting my mistake, I didn't mean to be rude.  I still have the feeling that is possible to recast this using combinations: weighting the outcomes by their probability of occurance means computing all the possible ways in which a certain election outcome could arise.

Comment: @Mr_3_7 It is possible to use Stars and Bars theory to attack the problem, but you have to be extremely careful.  That is, you have to group the solutions into subsets, where each element (i.e. solution) in a subset is equally likely.  Then, you have to assign *relative weights* to each subset, so that the subset's weight is assigned to each element in the subset.  This is typically **no walk in the park**.

Comment: @Mr_3_7 In the example given at the start of this answer, you would group the two solutions (2,0) and (0,2) into a subset, assigning the weight of 1 to that subset.  Then, you would create a separate subset that had the element (1,1), and assign a weight of 2 to that subset.  In my experience,  this approach is typically more trouble than its worth.  However, I have encountered problems where this approach gave a solution at least as elegant as other approaches.

Comment: @user2661923 yes, that's what I had in mind. First describe all the possible outcomes, then count all the ways in which it could materialise, but I don't have an exact feeling of how hard it could be